# How do I remove the "My account" and "Logout" links?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to sub-theme the [Bootstrap](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme. How do I  remove the *My account* and *Logout* links from the navigation bar?

Answer (score 3):

Try going to Appearance settings on your sub-theme `admin/appearance/settings/...` and uncheck Secondary menu.

If that doesn't work, check menu settings at `admin/structure/menu/settings` and make sure you haven't defaulted the main menu to "User menu".

Answer (score 1):

Go to: admin/structure/block
find user menu and set 'none', as region.

Comment: There is no blocks in navigation zone but I (as logged in user) still see the link. I guess the links are not a block but hardcoded somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, navigate to the user menu (admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu) and deselect "enabled" for each item.